# AWS Choosing a region or Choose budget

Tags: amazon-web-services

So, as the question title says,
How should we architect the solution using AWS ?

Do we need to consider the region first assuming we might  use all the features in future or stick with a region which is near and  *migrate*  to other regions for additional service,when needed.

How generally it is decided ?

Comment: This is way too broad of a question.  We know nothing about your environment or skillset.  I might start in the closest region but there are a huge number of variables.

Comment: hmm, what is the cost involved in setting up the same env from one region to another region ( appx) . This might  also be  a primary deciding factor in choosing the region first over budget ?

Comment: and also, i see some of the regions didn't have at least 50% of the services :-(

Comment: If you need a particular service you'll obviously need to work in a region that supports it.  Costs between regions are [pretty easy to find](https://calculator.aws/) but tend to be reasonably consistent.  Start with your architecture, deploy to a region that supports your architecture, and make your deployment reproducible (CloudFormation, AWS CDK, etc) so that you can move it from one place to another easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cost is fairly negligible when looking at various services pricing between regions, but obviously worth noting if you're on a very tight budget.

Regarding availability most commonly will services be available day 1 in the following regions:

- `us-east-1`
- `us-west-1`
- `eu-west-1`

You generally find that within a few weeks or months that services will be rolled out to other regions, with the exception of the China and Govcloud regions which can see a more significant delay.

New regions are generally deployed with a core set of services such as EC2, S3, RDS etc but after launch will start to add the remaining services there.

If your application is client facing (a client directly interacts with the application, over either a web browser or service API) then I believe geographical location can be more important to a degree than the pricing. Delivering as best an experience to the client in my opinion is more beneficial for example `us-east-1` might be cheaper but your clients based in europe.

If you want the cutting edge the regions listed above will almost always be current. Obviously you need to weigh all of these factors and decide based on what is most important for your usecase.

Comment: detailed explanation :-) . Would you mind sharing "general" best practises . There are many out there , but everything mostly says the most boring answer "IT DEPENDS" as usual

Comment: Most of these come from experience, a couple of good articles are https://cloudacademy.com/blog/how-to-choose-the-best-aws-region-for-your-workload/ and https://www.concurrencylabs.com/blog/choose-your-aws-region-wisely/. You'll always have your trade offs between the points made but it is my personal belief to go with the region that is going to provide the best experience for your customer :)